# UINavigationController stack issues with push and pop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So I have four view controllers, A, B, C, D and they are shown in that order. Let's say that I am at view C and I want to go to view D, so I push view controller D into the navigation controller stack, however, what I want is that when D tries to go back it goes directly to view controller B instead of C.

Is there a particular way to achieve this? The logical way is to do popViewController and then pushViewController: C. I tried this and it didn't work out.

Comment: "So I have *three* view controllers, A, B, C, D" - You need to correct that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the order is A->B->C->D right?  And from D, when the "Back" button is tapped you want to go to B?
That means popping D and then popping C so you get back to B.  That's what `popToViewController:animated:` does.
[UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> popToViewController:animated:
>
> Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the
>   top of the navigation stack.

Note that this is different from `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: When you're on D you only need to call it once.  What exactly are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing D, call `-setViewControllers:animated:` on your navigation controller with an array of view controllers ordered A, B, and D.

Comment: In general, this isn't a good practice because it can confuse users as to how to navigate through the interface in a way that they understand intuitively.

Comment: @Sean so then how would you git in solving it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` if A is at the bottom of the stack or `popToViewControllerAnimated:` if it's somewhere in the middle.

Comment: as I said, I did that already.. so when I am at view controller B and I want to load C.. I did popToViewControllerAnimated and then pushViewController:C, but it didn't work out

Comment: Okay, well then I'm confused about what you're saying here. Your stack is ABCD, then you want it to go to AB? But then you want to push C again to make it ABC?